# Proper use of <intent-filter>

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

What is the difference between these sets of intent filters?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="action1">
    <category android:name="category1">
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="action2">
    <category android:name="category2">
</intent-filter>
```

AND

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="action1">
    <category android:name="category1">
    <action android:name="action2">
    <category android:name="category2">
</intent-filter>
```

I think the first will only work if the intent action/category matches one of the pairs (i.e. action1/category1 and action2/category2 but not action1/category2 or action2/category1). The second will work with any combination of action & category provided.

Is that correct?

Comment: I would try a sample app to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html

> Action matches if any of the given values match the Intent action; if
>   the filter specifies no actions, then it will only match Intents that
>   do not contain an action.
>
> Categories match if all of the categories in the Intent match
>   categories given in the filter. Extra categories in the filter that
>   are not in the Intent will not cause the match to fail. Note that
>   unlike the action, an IntentFilter with no categories will only match
>   an Intent that does not have any categories.

So the first version would match these intents:

- act=action1
- act=action1 cat=[category1]
- act=action2
- act=action2 cat=[category2]

And the second would fit these:

- act=action1
- act=action1 cat=[category1]
- act=action1 cat=[category2]
- act=action1 cat=[category1,category2]
- act=action2
- act=action2 cat=[category1]
- act=action2 cat=[category2]
- act=action2 cat=[category1,category2]

As you can see it is possible to have more categories in an Intent, but you can have only one action.